# Stripe : appication deduction from a different account while the destination account stays the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

This query is related to a custom form of Payment on my Fundraising  Application

We want the Application fee to be deducted from our account(Application stripe account), so that the customer receives a payout without any deduction.

The overall fee per payout would be dealt with separately between Raise the money and the customer towards the end of the month.

For instance,

If the customer gets a donation of 100$, with an application fee of 4$. This fee of 4$ should be deducted from Raise the Money's account and the customer should be able to receive 100$.

Please guide us on this and let us know the API required to make it feasible.

Currently, we are using the Stripe Charge:

```
Stripe::Charge.create({
          
amount: amount_cents,
currency: candidate.candidate_country[candidate.country.to_s.to_sym][:currency],
source: stripe_token,
application_fee_amount: ((amount_cents * ((candidate.merchant_rate.to_f * 100) + 2.9) / 100) + 25).to_i,
statement_descriptor_suffix: "#{get_statement_descriptor.to_s.upcase}",
on_behalf_of: candidate.stripe_gateway_id,
transfer_data: {
destination: candidate.stripe_gateway_id,
},
}, stripe_version: '2019-12-03',)
```

The amount gets sent to the Customers account which is specified under destination params under transfer_data. In the current scenario, the application_fee_amount gets deduced from the same destination account.
What we are trying to achieve is appication_fee_amount deduction from a different account while the destination account stays the same.
Thanks in advance for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the application_fee parameter from your Destination Charge request so that your connected account can collect the full amount. Then, you can use [accounts debit](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-debits#charging-a-connected-account) to charge the connected account which you want to collect the application fee from:

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
  'amount'   => 4000,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'source' => '{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}'
]);
```

Please note that there is a geographical limitation and is only available in Australia, Canada, Europe, Hong Kong, Japan, New Zealand, and the U.S. Also, Account Debits only work when both the platform and the connected account are in the same region.

Comment: Appreciate the response, my question is what would happen to the Stripe fee(which is a part of the application fee)? Would it be deducted from my Platform?

Comment: With destination charges, you create a charge on your platform’s account so the payment appears as a charge on your account. In your use case, you transfer the full amount to the connected account. Your account balance is debited for the cost of the Stripe fees, refunds, and chargebacks. At the end of the month, you can run the Balance Transaction report [0] to calculate the `application_fee` for that month and use accounts debit to charge the connected account which you want to collect the application fee from.

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/reports/balance-transaction-types#connect_related